# Calculating the tag frequency for each movie using spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data-frame consisting of two column-movieid and the tags applied to that movie in the below format-

```
movieid   tag                                                                                     

1         animation
1         pixar 
1         animation 
2         comedy
```

I want to count for each movie id  how many times each tags are applied and also want to calculate total number of tags applied to each movie. I am new to spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in PySpark, here goes:

create the df:

```
 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
 data = [(1,'animation'),(1,'pixar'),(1,'animation'),(2,'comedy')]
 RDD = sc.parallelize(data)
 orders_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(RDD,["movieid","tag"])
 orders_df.show()

 +-------+---------+
 |movieid|      tag|
 +-------+---------+
 |      1|animation|
 |      1|    pixar|
 |      1|animation|
 |      2|   comedy|
 +-------+---------+
```

Calculate:

```
 orders_df.groupBy(['movieid','tag']).count().show() #count for each movie id how many times each tags are applied

 +-------+---------+-----+
 |movieid|      tag|count|
 +-------+---------+-----+
 |      1|    pixar|    1|
 |      1|animation|    2|
 |      2|   comedy|    1|
 +-------+---------+-----+

 orders_df.groupBy(['movieid']).count().show() #number of tags applied to each movie

 +-------+-----+
 |movieid|count|
 +-------+-----+
 |      1|    3|
 |      2|    1|
 +-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.It worked fine.The equivalent scala code is -          orders_df.groupBy("movieid","tag").count().show()